# Tooltip Initial delay not working in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, tooltip, delay

I created four buttons in WPF. And I use Tooltip for each button. I give an initial delay value to Tooltip. The Initial delay is working when I first time mouse hover to any of these button but when I move one button to another then no initial delay is triggered. I want to disable Tooltip when I move my mouse cursor from one button control to another. But unfortunately it's not working.

```xml
<Button
    Style="{StaticResource RoundCorner}"
    Name="button1"
    Width="71"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="381,14,0,0"
    Height="24"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    UseLayoutRounding="True"
    RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"
    RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
    ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="1000"
    ToolTipService.BetweenShowDelay="0"
    ToolTipService.ShowDuration="7000">
    <Button.Content>
        <TextBlock FontSize="10" FontFamily="Segoe UI" UseLayoutRounding="True" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
            Help
        </TextBlock>
    </Button.Content>
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip  UseLayoutRounding="True"  RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"  RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"   SnapsToDevicePixels="True" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock  FontFamily="Segoe UI"  FontSize="12"  TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal"    >
                    Help
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ToolTip>
    </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

Comment: You can use **ToolTipService.IsEnabled ="{Binding ElementName=button1, Path=IsFocused}"** to disable the tooltip for your button1.The button1's Tooltip will be diasbled , when it is not focused.

Comment: @DasiyTianMSFT your code is not working, I tried your data binding but unfortunately the ToolTip not appear after using your code, please give another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is cause by how much time the cursor spends travelling between elements which have tooltips. If there is no time or a very short time then the InitialShowDelay is ignored. This is essentially because the tooltipservice hasn't closed the first tooltip and it still has a tooltip open. It just picks up the tooltip content of the next button.

The simple solution is a gap between the buttons.

This ensures a previous tooltip has closed before the mouse is over another element with a tooltip.

Hence if you try the below:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Apple"
                ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="1000"   
                ToolTipService.BetweenShowDelay="2"
                ToolTip="An Apple"
                Margin="5"
                />
        <Button Content="Banana"
                ToolTip="A Banana"
                ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="1000"   
                ToolTipService.BetweenShowDelay="2"
                Margin="5"
                />
        <Button Content="Carrot"
                ToolTip="Orange Carrot"
                ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="1000"   
                ToolTipService.BetweenShowDelay="2"
                Margin="5"
                />
    </StackPanel>
```

There's a gap between the buttons and there will be a delay if you move the cursor from the first to second button.

[image]

In the picture, notice there is a gap between the buttons.

If you remove that margin I have on all the buttons there will be no gap and the second tooltip will show immediately when you move the mouse from the first to second button.

If you can only have a small gap then a rather more complicated solution is necessary. You need to null or close the tooltip immediately the mouse leaves one of the buttons.

One way to do that would be using a trigger.
Triggers set properties when their logic is satisfied so set the property to null using a style so it's null when the trigger is false.
When the mouse is over the button, set the tooltip to a value.
Thus the button only has a tooltip when the mouse is over it and our first tooltip will be nulled immediately the mouse moves off the button.

You need somewhere to put the tooltip markup and you could add an attached property but the below solution uses the button Tag.

**Minimal or No Gap:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay" Value="1000"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.BetweenShowDelay" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger  Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
   <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Apple">
            <Button.Tag>
                <TextBlock Text="This textBlock illustrates a more sophisticated tag" FontFamily="Segoe UI"  FontSize="12"/>
            </Button.Tag>
        </Button>

        <Button Content="Banana"
                Tag="A Banana"
                />
        <Button Content="Carrot"
                Tag="Orange Carrot"
                />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Note that the first button uses dot notation to illustrate how you would put any markup you like inside the tag rather than just the string the second and third buttons use.

If you want a style to incorporate the settings from another style you can use BasedOn:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="RoundCorner">
        .....
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource RoundCorner}">
```

This style has no key so it'll be applied to all buttons within it's scope. You could give the style a key if you don't want it applied to some buttons.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in my code actually, I posted only one button code, all my four button code is same and all of button controls are with proper margin and successfully closed with proper tag, but still it's not working.. please help.

Comment: @MERUNKUMARMAITY Your code is correct, I just tried it. When the buttons are right next to each other, the tooltip delay goes away. You have to add space between each button.

Comment: I have four buttons and each of them is closed by proper tag then why you see I have to add space between them ? What do you mean by that. I understand that adding proper space means closing the button with proper tags. If it is not can you explain more in details I can’t understand the “Add space “ term.

Comment: Set the values of Margin for your buttons to make them keep distance from each other.

Comment: Yes, it's not the closing tag is your problem. It's because there is no space between the buttons when rendered. If the cursor is moved and as it travels it goes straight from one button to another then you will get no delay. This is because there's no time where a tooltip is inappropriate. I've added a picture above. The arrow is pointing at a gap. If you have no MARGIN set then there would be no gap. You could use something other than margin.... so long as there is a gap between buttons when rendered.

Comment: I already given the proper space in my case the space is very minimum but still there some sufficient amount of space. All my buttons are separated with proper space and margin. All of them have different margin. Please give a decent solution.

Comment: I test your code, and it is no error as you descripted.Could you show the sample which can reproduce the issue for us to annalyze faster?

Comment: @MERUNKUMARMAITY I've extended the solution. Please try the markup above in an experimental new solution.

Comment: @Andy Actually, all of my four buttons are made by my own control template. And all values and attributes on that control template is totally defined by my own choice. So, the question is how I target that specific button in your style trigger. suppose my predefined control template key is "RoundCorner". I call this as a static style resource on each of this four button. Please help.

Comment: If you don't want to change roundcorner then extend it in a new style using basedon. Then use the extended style on these buttons.

Comment: @Andy Actually, I can not understand clearly what you say. Can please modify the code.?

Comment: @MERUNKUMARMAITY I've added an explanation of basedon.

Comment: @Andy please one last time modify the code and add that basedon property in the code. I am new to WPF only spend 4 months on it please last time help.

Comment: @Andy can you please explain this line  Value="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}". What type of data binding is this? Actually I applied this style trigger on my RoundedCorner button control template. And I can’t understand this data binding.

Comment: Self is whatever piece of UI the binding is within. Which is the button. And it's looking for the Tag property. Which is where I've put content for the Tooltip.

Comment: I assume that I don’t need to change any of the options on that Binding. Just add what you provided. I try but still there is no delay.

Comment: As long as I know the Tooltip is not a part of the Ui.Framework visual or logical part. So, how your data binding works? I contacted Microsoft on Twitter they say that. How you can do this kind of data binding?

Comment: The binding works because the style sets properties on a button. The button tooltip property is a property of the button. And relativesource self references whatever the binding is applied to. It's applied to the button.  Copy and paste the markup just beneath "minimal gap" into mainwindow of a new solution. Try it. See it work.

Comment: Can I can contact you on Reddit? or any other social media? Please help brother.

Comment: Sir, almost two years later I accepted your answer because now I have a good experience on WPF. But I have one last doubt, I wish you can reply me so that I can tell you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is wrong with the ToolTipService but the only thing that works for me is to set BetweenShowDelay to a small integer value and then the behavior I'm looking for works. I know the documentation says BetweenShowDelay should be in milliseconds but when I try to use a ms value, tooltips will be immediately displayed as I mouseover one control to the next after the InitialShowDelay as elapsed for one control. I even checked the .NET reference source and I could not find an issue with the code (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/PopupControlService.cs,dd8bf024ff5d4d74)

This is what works for me:

```
<StackPanel>    
    <Button ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="2000"
            ToolTipService.BetweenShowDelay="1"
            ToolTip="Say something" />

    <Button ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="2000"
            ToolTipService.BetweenShowDelay="1"
            ToolTip="Say something else" />
</StackPanel>
```

After the "Say something" tooltip displays, if I mouseover the next button, the tooltip won't display until the initial delay of 2000ms has elapsed. This isn't how the documentation and reference source says it should work but this is how I got it to work for me to get the intended behavior.